# Sorting Gridview in Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, dataview

I am trying to sort a gridview in visual basic using the following method, however the second line of code (Dim dv as DataView...) throws a NullReferenceException. When I debug the code and step through it, I can see that the DataTable dt has a value of "Nothing" after it is instantiated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        Dim dt As DataTable = grdExpProd.DataSource
        Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView

        If (blnExTraining) Then
            dv.Sort = "ExpirationDate DESC"
        Else
            dv.Sort = "ExpirationDate ASC"
        End If

        grdExpProd.DataSource = dv
        grdExpProd.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After postback the DataSource of any Web-Databound-Control like `GridView` is Nothing (null in C#). Note that HTTP is stateless, all objects that are created  in a page's life-cycle will be destroyed as soon as the page was rendered.

So the solution is easy, select the `DataSource` again with the correct `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Since the datasource was a call to an SQL datatbase, does this mean I have to re-query the database again?